# Transpose columns and delete rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have ~10000 rows with 6 columns. Some rows have column A to E identical and F has unique values. 
Lets say from A2 to A7 are identical but F2 to F7 have unique values. How can i put F2 to F7 in G2 to M2 and delete the rows A3 to A7 ? I use G2=IF(A2=A3,F3,"") repeated to V17=IF(A16=A17,F17,"") but i have to eliminate the rows and i don't know how to do this.

For the extraction i am using:

```
Sub extract()

Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myitems As Outlook.Items
Dim myitem As Object
Dim Found As Boolean

Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myitems = GetFolderPatharchive("aaa\bbb").Items
Found = False

    Dim olkMsg As Object, _
        olkFld As Object, _
        excApp As Object, _
        excWkb As Object, _
        excWks As Object, _
        intRow As Integer, _
        intCnt As Integer, _
        data_email As String, _
        strFilename As String, _
        arrCells As Variant, _
        varb As Variant, varD As Variant, varF As Variant

        strFilename = "C:\OVERVIEW\EXTRACT"
        If strFilename <> "" Then
        Set excApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set excWkb = excApp.Workbooks.Add()
        Set excWks = excWkb.ActiveSheet
        excApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        With excWks
            .Cells(1, 1) = "SENDER"
            .Cells(1, 2) = "SUBJECT"
            .Cells(1, 3) = "CITY"
            .Cells(1, 4) = "DATE"
            .Cells(1, 5) = "HOUR"
            .Cells(1, 6) = "PROBLEM"
        End With
        intRow = 2

        For Each olkMsg In myitems
        If olkMsg.Class = olMail Then

                arrCells = Split(GetCells(olkMsg.HtmlBody), Chr(255))

                For intCnt = LBound(arrCells) To UBound(arrCells) Step 1

 On Error GoTo Handler

    varb = arrCells(intCnt)

    Dim linie As Integer
    linie = InStr(olkMsg.Subject, "-")


                excWks.Cells(intRow, 1) = olkMsg.SenderName
                excWks.Cells(intRow, 2) = Left(olkMsg.Subject, linie - 1) 
                excWks.Cells(intRow, 3) = Left(olkMsg.Subject, 4)
                excWks.Cells(intRow, 4) = Format(olkMsg.ReceivedTime, "dd.mm.yyyy")
                excWks.Cells(intRow, 5) = Format(olkMsg.ReceivedTime, "Hh:Nn:Ss")
                excWks.Cells(intRow, 6) = varb

                intRow = intRow + 1
Next
            End If

Label1:
        Next

        Set olkMsg = Nothing
        excWkb.SaveAs strFilename, 52
        excWkb.Close
    End If

    Set olkFld = Nothing
    Set excWks = Nothing
    Set excWkb = Nothing
    Set excApp = Nothing

    MsgBox "Ta dam!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly

Call opexlN
    Exit Sub
Handler:

  If olkMsg <> "Nothing" Then

  MsgBox "..."

  Else: End

End If
Resume Label1:

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to delete rows or to delete columns? I can't understand it from your question.

Comment: Hi, i have to delete the A3-A7 rows because the data from F3-F7 will be put in G2-M2 so i don't need the rows A3 to A7.

Comment: Transfer to array, use a dictionary to extract unique values into another array and then write back to the sheet.

Comment: You may use Range.EntireRow.Delete but it will be slow for 10000 rows, so SJR's idead would be best.